# Problems in Packaging files for installation in my project

Tags: python

I am trying to make a project in Python and was using Pydev to make it.For better structuring I divided all of them into mini packages for better handling of where each code lies....

I have run into problems with actually packaging all of them into a single file for installation.....

In eclipse I had made packages and interlinked them with statements like

```
import Package1.File1
```

I observed that in each of the package a blank `__init__.py` exists

However since this files are not directly into the path of the system when I try to run them with IDLE I get an error saying that Package1 does not exist.....

So I want to ask 2 questions ....

1) If I currently just make a package of all the files that I have will I have to make eclipse as a requirement for running the files ??

2) I observed that if I add all the folders in the site-packages folder of the python installation the error disappears ..... Is there any way I can make sure that all the files go into that folder during installation and is that the correct way to do it ??

Thanks a lot for all your advices and suggestions

Comment: `I have run into problems with actually packaging all of them into a single file for installation.` Don't do that... Keep the module structure. Why would you put them all back into one file?

Comment: I meant that combining all of them into an exe so that it could be easily installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In development you can set `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to define where modules will sit.
2. For something like this, I think what you want is to use [distutils](http://docs.python.org/distutils/index.html#distutils-index) to setup an installation process.  One part of the process will install files to the default location for each machine.  There should also be a way to install a script in the bin directory (/usr/bin or /usr/local/bin) depending on who is installing it.  Django does this when it installs.
3. You will leave your module structure the same and distutils will handle the install.  Of course you'll need to work through the distutils documentation and look at examples.  Then come back and ask a more specific question if you run into problems...

Answer (score 1):

> I have run into problems with actually
>   packaging all of them into a single
>   file for installation.

Don't do that... Keep the module structure. Why would you put them all back into one file?

Yes you will either need to put your modules in dist-packages or add the location of your module to the PYTHONPATH enviornmental variable. Take a look at [distutils](http://docs.python.org/distutils/index.html#distutils-index) for distributing your program.

Eclipse has absolutely nothing to do with packages.

Answer (score 0):

Does Package1 also have a blank `__init__.py`? If so the problem with IDLE is rather that Package1 isn't in PYTHONPATH. Make sure your current dirrectory during development is the directory above Package1.

This obviously doesn't work when running the software in production, then it should, as you noticed, be installed in site-packages . The way to install the packages into site-packages in the correct way is called "[distutils](http://docs.python.org/library/distutils.html)".

(Well, OK, strictly speaking, site-packages is only *one* way to install it, but the other correct ways also relies on distutils).